# How to pass constants to a method?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism, constants

I have this classes:
package util;

```
public final class Constant {

    private Constant() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    public static class Product {
        public static final String CODE = "Product";
        public static final String A = "product_5g2g";
        public static final String B = "product_a45h";
        public static final String C = "product_a3ag";
        //more constants..
    }

    public static class Employee {
        public static final String CODE = "Employee";
        public static final String A = "employee_1g3f";
        public static final String B = "employee_h52d";
        public static final String C = "employee_h5d2";
        //more constants..
   }

    public static class Client {
        public static final String CODE = "Client";
        public static final String A = "client_h5ad";
        public static final String B = "client_1df1";
        public static final String C = "client_6g23";
        //more constants..
    }
}
```

and:

```
package util;

import util.Constant.*;

public class Main {

    public void run() {
        if (isSelected(Product.CODE)) {
            if (isSelected(Product.A) || isSelected(Product.B)) {
                //do something
            }
            compute(Product.C);
            //more similar instruction that use constants from Product class
        }
        if (isSelected(Employee.CODE)) {
            if (isSelected(Employee.A) || isSelected(Employee.B)) {
                //do something
            }
            compute(Employee.C);
            //more similar instruction that use constants from Employee class
        }
        if (isSelected(Client.CODE)) {
            if (isSelected(Client.A) || isSelected(Client.B)) {
                //do something
            }
            compute(Client.C);
            //more similar instruction that use constants from Client class
        }
    }

    public boolean isSelected(String s) {
        return true;
    }

    public void compute(String s) {

    }
}
```

As you can see, this block of code

```
if (isSelected(StaticClass.CODE)) {
    if (isSelected(StaticClass.A) || isSelected(StaticClass.B)) {
        //do something
    }
    compute(StaticClass.C);
    //more similar instruction that use constants from Product class
}
```

is repetitive, but can't put it in a separate method because java don't permit a static class as a parameter `public void method(StaticClass) {}`.

How can I refactor the above code? My first thought was to make Singletons that extend a base class, or implement an common interface. There is a better solution?

Comment: Did you check Enums?

Comment: I would recomment Enums and thinking about switch-case and extracting methods.

Comment: @Jorji You have two answers to your question. Please leave a comment on the answers if you need further clarification or accept one of the answers as the correct one by clicking on the tick mark. Voting up is free. Accepting an answer gives you two points. You have nothing to lose. Do let me know if you have any concerns that are stopping you from commenting or accepting the answers.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an `Enum`. Redefine all your classes as `Enum`s instead. For example, you can redfine the `Product` class as follows :

```
public enum Product {
   CODE("Product"),
   A("product_5g2g");

   private String value;
   //define others constants in a similar fasion
   public Product(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
}
```

`Enums` can be passed as method parameters. In your particular example, you can do this :

```
public void method(Constants.Product product) {

}
```

That said, you should definitely look into an alternative way to achieve your objective. Take a  look at [Replacing conditionals with Polymorphism](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html) for starters.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using **polymorphism** here. Example: instead of doing

```
if (X) {
 doY();
}
```

"good" OO looks much more like:

```
Y y = getMeSomeY();
y.doTheY();
```

Where `getMeSomeY()` returns you exactly that what is required (so `Y` could be an interface; and that method provides different implementations of that interface which all do slightly different things).
The point is: you wrote *procedural* code, where you *ask* something, to then make a decision about it. Good OO favors the opposite (called [tell don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)).

You start by ... not making everything flat strings. By doing so, you give up on the whole "static typing" thing. If your code is making decisions only on strings, why are you programming in Java? You can very well use a non-typed language than. So, at least learn about Java enums; and use those. But please understand: enums are not the *real* answer here. They would just help to make your code a bit better.

The **real** problem here is that you want to write code doing these `if (x) then y` all over the place.

You might have guessed by now: there is no easy answer here. What I would do: first, step back. And have a in-depth look into your design. The code you have right now indicates to me that your underlying *object model* is far from "helpful". And that is the whole point of OO: you create classes and objects that *help* you to write clean, elegant code.  But when your base design isn't supporting that; then there is no point in trying to refactor the code that came out of that. Because the ugliness of your code is just a symptom; the root cause lies in your *design* underneath.

Comment: `getMeSomeY()` with an argument would make more sense ;)